# Inserting csv files from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery through a Cloud Function

Tags: json, node.js, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I want to write data from csv files into a BigQuery table.

I have built the following data pipeline for that end:
csv file in Cloud Storage <=> GCS Text to PubSub DataFlow <=> Cloud Function <=> BigQuery table.

The Cloud Function is configured to be triggered upon arrival of a new message in the PubSub topic.
My function execution keeps failing due to the data extracted from the PubSub JSON message not being in the correct JSON format before insertion in BigQuery. I have tried to modify the data format in the csv file but it desperately keeps failing up to a point where I wonder if this is even possible. The same pipeline with an NDJSON source file works like a charm and writes in BQ.

1) Here is my table (11 fields):
Member_ID INTEGER First_Name STRING
Last_Name                  STRING
Gender                     STRING
Age                        INTEGER
Height                     INTEGER
Weight                     INTEGER
Hours_Sleep                INTEGER
Calories_Consumed          INTEGER
Exercise_Calories_Burned   INTEGER
Date                       DATE

2) Here is my function:

```js
/**
 * Background Cloud Function to be triggered by PubSub.
 *
 * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 */
exports.subscribe = function (event, callback) {
  const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const projectId = "iot-fitness-198120"; //Enter your project ID here
  const datasetId = "CDCData"; //Enter your BigQuery dataset name here
  const tableId = "fitness"; //Enter your BigQuery table name here
  const PubSubMessage = event.data;
  console.log(`Le Message PubSub en base64 est: ${PubSubMessage}`);
  // Incoming data is in JSON format
  const incomingData = PubSubMessage.data ? Buffer.from(PubSubMessage.data, 'base64').toString() : "{'Member_ID':'na','First_Name':'na','Last_Name':'na','Gender':'na','Age':'na','Height':'na','Weight':'na','Hours_Sleep':'na','Calories_Consumed':'na','Exercise_Calories_Burned':'na','Date':'na'}";
  console.log(`Le Message PubSub en String est: ${incomingData}`);
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(incomingData);
  console.log(`Le Message PubSub parse en JSON est: ${jsonData}`);
  var rows = [jsonData];

  console.log(`Incoming data: ${rows}`);

  // Instantiates a client
  const bigquery = BigQuery({
    projectId: projectId
  });
  console.log(`BigQuery Client instantiated`);
  // Inserts data into a table
  bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows)
    .then((insertErrors) => {
      console.log('Inserted:');
      rows.forEach((row) => console.log(row));

      if (insertErrors && insertErrors.length > 0) {
        console.log('Insert errors:');
        insertErrors.forEach((err) => console.error(err));
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
  // [END bigquery_insert_stream]

  callback();
};
```

3) lastly, below is the main error message when trying to import the following simple csv file: 123456,Jack,Jones,F,39,183,130,8,2501,990,2017-11-09.

```js
2018-03-19 22:44:40.585 GST
function-fitnessPubSubToBQ
58216840933966
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 6 at Object.parse (native) at exports.subscribe (/user_code/index.js:17:25) at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:16 at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:660:9 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
Expand all | Collapse all {
 insertId:  "000000-2437f842-1bab-47c3-9583-b91ffd0cc601"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/iot-fitness-198120/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-03-19T18:44:45.895841517Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 6
    at Object.parse (native)
    at exports.subscribe (/user_code/index.js:17:25)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:16
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:660:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)"  
 timestamp:  "2018-03-19T18:44:40.585Z"  
}
```

It complains about the data format and upon executing "JSON.parse(incomingData);"
How can I get the data to be formatted before JSON parsing ?

Thanks.

Comment: I may be missing something, but are you trying to execute "JSON.parse(incomingData)", with the incomingData in CSV format? Or is there another process that turns the source data in CSV format to JSON format? What is the log output of console.log(`Le Message PubSub en String est: ${incomingData}`);?

Comment: A CSV file with multiple rows is turned into a single message in JSON format first by the "GCS Text to PubSub" DataFlow. Challenge is I don’t know the internal structure of that JSON payload.
Log output of console.log(Le Message PubSub en String est: ${incomingData}); is "Le Message PubSub en String est: 123456,Jack,Jones,F,39,183,130,8,2501,990,2017-11-09"
So indeed, JSON.parse(incomingData); is parsing a simple string and fails. It's the previous line, const incomingData = PubSubMessage.data ? Buffer.from(PubSubMessage.data, 'base64').toString(), that transforms the JSON payload to string.

Comment: May I suggest a completely different and easier approach. Instead of your current architecture, which may not scale very well, consider this: `GCS -> Cloud Function -> Dataflow (template) -> BigQuery`. Using Dataflow to load the file in one shot using a BigQuery load job is cleaner IMHO. It also gives you stackdriver monitoring & error reporting out of the box. You could ditch Dataflow if you want, and simply call a BigQuery load job directly from the Cloud Function i.e. `GCS -> Cloud Function -> BigQuery` . That will also work.

Comment: By "GCS -> Cloud Function -> Dataflow (template) -> BigQuery" you mean using the "GCS Text to BigQuery" Dataflow and getting it triggered by a Cloud Function upon file upload in GCS, right ?

Comment: You can add/check more print/log statement to check the data format at each stage.

It is also likely that the data is always in CSV format.

Comment: _"GCS Text to BigQuery"_ : not sure what you mean by this. But yes, file is uploaded to GCS, which triggers a cloud function to spin up a Dataflow pipeline, ingest the file and writes it to BigQuery.

Comment: OK, the alternative you're describing is exactly what I'm working on right now. The Dataflow pipeline works well BUT I am having issues when trying to automate it using a triggered Cloud function as you suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379756/triggering-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-from-cloud-function-function-times-out      Any idea why it is not triggering ?

Comment: Are you doing some data transformation of your table? How many files are uploaded? As @Graham commented, you may  discard the use of Dataflow so the process will be simple.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had this same problem until I reformatted the CSV file as NDJSON and saved it with the .json extension.  Then it worked like a charm.