# Triggering Cloud Dataflow pipeline from Cloud Function - function times out

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to trigger a Dataflow pipeline from a Cloud Function which itself is triggered upon upload of a new file in a GCS bucket.
When I upload a file, the Cloud function gets triggered properly but timesout after few seconds without any Dataflow being triggered.
Below is my function code:

```js
const google = require('googleapis');
const projectId = "iot-fitness-198120";
 
exports.moveDataFromGCStoPubSub = function(event, callback) {
 const file = event.data;
 if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.name) {
   google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }
 
     if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
       authClient = authClient.createScoped([
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
       ]);
     }
     console.log("File exists and client function is authenticated");
     console.log(file);
     
 
     const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
     console.log(`Incoming data: ${file.name}`);
 
     dataflow.projects.templates.create({
       projectId: projectId,
       resource: {
         parameters: {
           inputFile: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`,
           outputTopic: `projects/iot-fitness-198120/topics/MemberFitnessData`
         },
         jobName: 'CStoPubSub',
         gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub',
         staginglocation: 'gs://fitnessanalytics-tmp/tmp'
       }
     }, function(err, response) {
       if (err) {
         console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
       }
       console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
       callback();
     });
 
   });
 }
};
```

The execution doesn't even log the following line, console.log("File exists and client function is authenticated"); which tells me it is not even getting that far.

Here's the log output during execution:

2018-03-20 04:56:43.283 GST
DataflowTriggeringFunction
52957909906492
Function execution took 60097 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

2018-03-20 04:55:43.188 GST
DataflowTriggeringFunction
52957909906492
Function execution started

Any idea why it's not triggering the Dataflow and yet not throwing an error message ?

Answer (score 4):

I have finally modified the code. Got some help from GCP support. Below is the right syntax that works:

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');

exports.moveDataFromGCStoPubSub = (event, callback) => {


const file = event.data;
const context = event.context;

console.log(`Event ${context.eventId}`);
console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);

  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

 console.log(projectId);

 const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
 console.log(`gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`);
 dataflow.projects.templates.create({
  gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub', 
  projectId: projectId,
   resource: {
    parameters: {
        inputFilePattern: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`,
        outputTopic: 'projects/iot-fitness-198120/topics/MemberFitnessData2'
      },
    environment: {
      tempLocation: 'gs://fitnessanalytics-tmp/tmp'
    },
      jobName: 'CStoPubSub',
      //gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub',    
    }
 }, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
     console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
   }
   console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
   callback();
 });

   });

 callback();
};
```

Comment: I've tried your code and for some reason I'm getting permission issues:

problem running dataflow template, error was: { Error: A Forbidden error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have the correct permission scopes specified. (cbfa072458b51d1e): Template file failed to load: Permissions denied. Please check the file permissions

I've given the cloud function and compute robot accounts project owner, however this is still failing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Guess your cloud function execution fails doesn't satisfy your if statement,

```
if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.name)
```

I had similar issue when I started working on Cloud Function. Modify your index.js file `var {google} = require('googleapis');` as provided in the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348220/google-cloud-functions-cannot-read-property-getapplicationdefault)

Comment: Thanks Vetri. It did help a lot indeed. I am copying your template now and adapting it to my needs. However, it is still not going through. Apparently, this is because I am mis-writing a required parameter for my job to complete, the stagingLocation parameter. Any idea how it should be writen in the code: staging-location ? stagingLocation ? staginglocation ? In the CLI, it is --staging-location.

Comment: I assume you are asking about cloud function js file. it is stagingLocation and looks like
'--jobName=FromACloudFunction',
         '--project=analytics-project', 
         '--runner=DataflowRunner',
         '--stagingLocation=gs://mybucket/staging'